# Error is thrown when array is passed to eloquent object

Tags: php, eloquent, slim

I'm having some trouble to insert data on a One to Many relationship using Eloquent. When I pass an array to the object as the documentation states an error is thrown and when I echo `$ex->getMessage()` only the index of the array I'm trying to pass("number") is printed. Does anybody have any idea why this happens?

```
public static function insert(Request $request, Response $response) {
        try {
            $data = $request->getParsedBody();

            $user = new \User;
            $user->name = $data['name'];
            $user->flag = $data['flag'];
            $user->login = $data['login'];
            $user->password = md5(SALT . $data['password']);
            //$user->save();

            foreach ($data['phoneNumbers'] as $key => $number) {
                $phonenumber[$key] = new \Phonenumber(array("number" => $number));
            }

            $user->phonenumbers()->saveMany($phonenumber);

            $meta = Helper::retornaMetaArray(Enum::SUCS_STS, Enum::CREATED, 201);

            return $response->withCustomJson(null, $meta);
        } catch (Exception $ex) {
            echo $ex->getMessage();
        }
    }
```

This is what I'm sending on the request body:

```
{
    "name": "Jon Snow",
    "login": "jon",
    "password": "ghost",
    "flag": "1",
    "phoneNumbers": ["(82) 99178-1066", "(82) 99303-9037"]
}
```

Comment: in the code you posted, you aren't echoing the exception message

Comment: I'm sorry, I just deleted the echo by mistake. It's ok now.

Comment: also, you are calling `saveMany` with `$telefones` but shouldn't it be `$phonenumber`?

Comment: Yes, I've chaged it. I've translated all variables to english so it can be more easily read by everybody. Forgot one.

Comment: not about language, I mean, it looks like a typo... in your `foreach` loop you are loading up the `$phonenumber` array with `new \Phonenumber`s, but then after the `foreach` loop you are doing a `saveMany` with the variable `$telefones` which appears to be undefined.

Comment: As I said It's correct now.

Comment: no its not... `$user->phonenumbers()->saveMany(` **$telefones** `);`... where is the variable `$telefones` defined?

Comment: Sorry, yet another typo. But this isn't on my original code. The thing is that the error is thrown before the ´saveMany()´, the problem is exactly when I pass the parameter to the Phonenumber object. If I stop the script after the foreach the error is still thrown.